# proof for $(1 + i)^n =(\sqrt{2})^n(\cos(\frac{n\pi}4) + i\sin(\frac{n\pi}4))$

Tags: complex-numbers, proof-writing

How would I prove

$(1 + i)^n =(\sqrt{2})^n(\cos(\pi n/4) + i\sin(\pi n/4))$

for all positive integers $n$

Answer (score 2):

Note that $(i+1)^n=\sqrt{2}^n \cdot (\frac{i+1}{2})^n=\sqrt{2}^n \cdot (\cos \frac{\pi}{4}+i \sin \frac{\pi}{4})^n=\sqrt{2}^n \cdot e^{n\frac{i\pi}{4}}=\sqrt{2}^n \cdot (\cos \frac{n\pi}{4}+i\sin \frac{n\pi}{4})$
using [Euler's Formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler's_formula) twice.

Alternatively (if you don't want to use that formula), you could use mathematical induction over $n$ and apply some trigonometric identities to simplify the result.

Answer (score 0):

$1+i = \sqrt 2 (\cos \arctan 1 + i\sin \arctan 1) = \sqrt 2 (\cos \frac{\pi}{4} + i \sin \frac{\pi}{4})$

Now apply [De Moivre's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Moivre%27s_formula):

$(1+i)^n = (\sqrt 2)^n (\cos \frac{\pi}{4} + i \sin \frac{\pi}{4})^n = (\sqrt 2)^n (\cos \frac{n\pi}{4} + i \sin \frac{n\pi}{4})$

You don't necessarily have to invoke Euler's formula here, although it quickly leads to the same result.